# Filtering Spark Dataset[Row] switch casing Column value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The question may sound simplistic to those experienced at first but what I'm trying to achieve is the following...

My current `Dataset[Row]` has a `Column('COLOR')` object which contain some values, `red`, `blue` or `green`.

> The logic that I want to apply is that `given a Column value, check
>   that the Row itself, so that its Columns contain certain properties accoridng to that value.`

So far I know that I can take a `Column` object and filter out its value by a given condition, say `.equalTo("this")` or `.gt(new Date())`, but what if I want to conditionally filter the overall Column based on the possible values incoming within the `Column`?

What I've thought so far is to perform a `.equalTo` which value is the result of a function...

```
def isValid(column: Column): String = ???
```

Which internally retrieves the value from the `Column`, applies a `case`and returns the value of the `Column` if the validation went well, or empty string if the validation went wrong.

Also tried receiving a `Row` in the previous method, but can't really figure out how to use `row.getData()` which returns `util.List[Datum]`.

This seems way too over-engineered to me and there has to be a simpler solution to apply a conditional filtering within a Column.

**EDIT**:

Input

```
id,   color, fruit,      origin,  eaten
----------------------------------------
0,    red,   apple,      france,  true
1,    blue,  strawberry, spain,   *doesn't exist in this Row*
```

If I apply a filtering of (pseudocode)...

```
color match {    
     case 'blue' -> hasColumn('eaten') and isFruit('blueberry')
     case 'red' -> hasColumn('eaten') and isFruit('apple') 
}
```

Only `id == 0` should be included in the Dataset after applying the filtering.

Comment: Can you please share an example of input and desired out?

Comment: @czr_RR can you share the output dataset as well. If i am getting the question right, this can be easily achieved by using case statement.

Comment: What do you mean by `*doesn't exist in this Row*`?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala with that I mean that a given field is null, whereas other Row does contain value for that Column.

Comment: @Goldie the output is what Nir posted in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use UDF

```
val udf = (row: Row) => {
        val maybeFruit = getValueFromRow[String](row, "Fruit")
        getValueFromRow[String](row, "Color").exists(_ match {
          case "Red" => maybeFruit.contains("Apple")
          case "Blue" => maybeFruit.contains("Rasp")
          case "Green" => maybeFruit.contains("Grape")
        })
      }

def getValueFromRow[T](row: Row, fieldName: String): Option[T] =
      Try(row.fieldIndex(fieldName)) match {
        case Success(nodeIdx) =>
          if (!row.isNullAt(nodeIdx)) Some(row.getAs[T](nodeIdx))
          else None
        case Failure(_) => None
      }

df.filter(col("Eaten")).filter(udf).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+------+
| ID|Fruit|Color|Eaten|Origin|
+---+-----+-----+-----+------+
|  0|Apple|  Red| true|France|
+---+-----+-----+-----+------+
```